# FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION makes Action Bar transparent

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I'm trying to make Navigation Bar transparent, but keep Action Bar as it is.
Following code makes both transparent:

```
Window w = getWindow();
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
```

Please suggest how to make transparent Navigation Bar only.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit :**
After reading the source, i understood the problem. The OP has not declared the styles in a proper way ie., the custom themes were not extending the default themes. Hence it made the actionbar to be transparent.

Previous Answer :

If you are targeting kitkat and above, add the following to your style. (Else do it in values-v19 styles file)

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

this will make the navigation bar translucent.

Or you can do it programmatically,

```
Window w = getWindow();
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: Didn't help, the Action Bar still transparent. The app is very simple, Activity with white background. If I run without FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION - Action Bar and Nav Bar are black. With this flag - both white.

Comment: are you sure that you are not doing anything else with actionbar?

Comment: I'm not doing anything with actionbar. setFlags() removed.Here are the [project files](http://www.mediafire.com/download/poubjb83k1igodi/nav_bar.zip). Running on 4.4.4.

Comment: Your styles must extend a parent theme. For eg; <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">

Comment: Yes! I set parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" as per your suggestion, and it worked perfectly! Please update your answer (since the solution here is "parent", doesn't matter how you set windowTranslucentNavigation) and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!